How is gl_FragCoord generated?
I'm thinking it is generated when program is in process of rasterization , based on gl_position. And since its range begins with (0.5,0.5) , I'd think it becomes available after a primitive is entirely mapped to pixels .
Am I correct that gl_fragcoord is not a value ranged in (0,1) . So it is not in NDC . NDC is not the final stage. After it , we have to remap (0,1) range to screen size. gl_fragcoord is here describing screen size .
It sounds rational because rasterization happens on screen . But how is gl_fragcoord.z generated ? Why is gl_fragcoord equal to 1/w ? Did W-division already happen before we move into the rasterization stage ? Does opengl program automatically perform clipping and W-division on gl_position after all vertex processing finished ?
I see people discussing what is clipping space and why is it important , but when it comes to what should we do on raw vertex input , we simply give it projectionMatrix*viewMatrix . It is impossible clipping happens by projection matrix right ? So I'm thinking if clipping is already a built-in process .
W-division is after clipping . Does opengl automatically map vertices to NDC coordinate ? Then is it necessary to map vertices into [-1,1] range in vertex shader ? But the fact is opengl will clip all that is beyond NDC cube and output only things inside NDC . That is to say we have to project twice. Once for projecting frustum to near plane , the second time for projecting near plane to [-1,1] range . All these projection must be included in projection matrix .
If I got input vertices already in [-1,1] range , i.e. the mesh is small enough , then I can directly pass it into gl_Position with no additional processing . Finally all that is in NDC gets rendered . I've tested on it and it was proven true. You can really just send vertices , and simply put a scale matrix on them to scale them down into the range of [-1,1] , and then output . The render will be ok . But for this test , there exists no perspective frustum neither ortho projection matrix. The only matrix that has been put on mesh was a scaling matrix . There is no near plane neither far plane . How does opengl generate gl_fragcoord.z , which I think might be (vertex.z-nearplane.z)/(farplane.z-nearplane.z) ?
W-division seems to be automatic . I changed the w value of gl_position , and the final effects was scaled . So the thing I need to do in vertex shader is calculating out what is the w , however leaving xyz in a incomplete state of being multiplied by nearplane.z ? To be fair such values would be meaningless . You can't even display them on screen , because they're done halfway. They become meaningful after W is divided . I'm not sure opengl is expecting to perform clipping on those meaningless data.

Clipping is performed on the clip position (gl_Position). Clip condition: -w < x, y, z < w

@Rabbid76 Isn't it -1<x,y,z<1 ? As only NDC is preserved .

No. Clipping is performed in clip space. Think about negative w components.

@Rabbid 76 I've gone through the answer . I understand it now . But what's the point making clip range equal with perspective parameter ?

@Shahashahaha because it makes sense to save computations, we don't need to do extra work dividing all vertex positions to decide if its clipped or not

@AlexeyS.Larionov Sorry but may I ask what do you mean by 'extra work' and 'it's clipped or not' ?

Suppose GPU loads the gl_Position that you wrote in the shader. You have millions of vertices every frame, very little time to wasting computations. Half the vertices maybe get clipped, but GPU doesn't know yet. We already have gl_Position.w in memory, so just need to check something that in GLSL can look like all(gl_Position < gl_Position.w) && all(gl_Position > -gl_Position.w)). Then we clip half the vertices and divide by w for only half the vertices (division is expensive),

@AlexeyS.Larionov Thanks for your explanation , it gets clear for me

A lot of questions, and a lot of confusion.
Let's refer to the gl_FragCoord docs, it is a vector with window relative coordinate (x, y, z, 1/w), in pixels, i.e. ranges from 0 to width/height of the framebuffer.
The (0.5, 0.5) offset is also in pixels, i.e. a fragment in the origin of the window space will have coordinates (0.5, 0.5), 10 fragments to the right would have coordinates (10.5, 0.5). The fractional offset is related to the fact, that a pixel is not a little square (that's a great article by the way). There is a distinction between a pixel on a physical display (a circuit that emits light, which has some noticeable physical size), and on the other hand, the pixel in software, which is a sample of color (nothing more). I.e. it's a single infinitely small point with some coordinates, where we determine the color value. We can choose any coordinates for this sample, it makes most sense to select these coordinates inside physical pixel. Assuming that in our notation 1 physical pixel corresponds to 1 unit, the offset (0.5, 0.5) means we sample color at center of a physical pixel.
What's the order of rasterization? It may depend on hardware implementation, but roughly it can look like that.

You output vertex data out of vertex shader.
We determine which vertices will be clipped (how it's computed, I describe later).
At this point, the primitives don't yet exist (no trianges, no quads). The primitives get assembled. Importantly, if any vertex of a triangle was clipped, then the triangle is replaced by two or more triangles, so that all triangles have positions inside clip space.
Rasterizing the triangle, that is generating fragments (finding pixel locations inside the triangle, using interpolation of gl_Position.xyz from triangle vertices. I think w division can happen at this point, because we need to do perspective correct interpolation, so that we can compute fragment positions efficiently of GPU, i.e. linearly, which would be a simple adding of a constant offset between neighboring pixels. For this purpose, we need to compute 1/w (see the article)
Early tests can be used at this point to compare depth of each fragment against depth buffer, stencil buffer. It can reduce unnecessary work
For all remaining fragments, we need to generate inputs for the fragments (in variables in the fragment shader out of out variables of vertex shader). For this we similarly need to interpolate the values using all 3 vertices in the triangle. And also we need to do perspective correct interpolation here.
Now we call the fragment shader, with all its in values, and OpenGL provided constants, such as gl_FragCoord, with XYZ from the interpolated gl_Position, and XY are also scaled to the viewport parameters. The gl_FragCoord.w is 1/w because we already needed to compute it for perspective correct interpolation

That's about it.
So, going back, clipping works like that - it clips any vertex, for which gl_Position.xyz any value is outside -gl_Position.w; gl_Position.w range (the clip space). In your vertex shader you outputs vertices, e.g. through some computation somehow you output
gl_Position = vec4(0.5, 5.3, -4.2, 5.5);

notice it's outside NDC range (-1;1), but no XYZ coordinate is outside -w;w range, the vertex is kept. For
gl_Position = vec4(0.5, 5.3, -4.2, 4.5);

the vertex is clipped, because y > w.
This simple rule explains your other questions

You don't have to output vertices in NDC range, but in -w; w range in order to not be clipped
The computation that leads you to writing to gl_Position also doesn't matter, just return a gl_Position in -w; w range. So using no matrices is ok, using a mesh that is already -w; w range is ok.
There is no concept of projection matrix / perspective / orthographic / near / far planes, none of that is tracked for rasterization. And more importantly it can't be tracked, notice that you only output gl_Position, never something like gl_Near or gl_ProjectionMatrix. Thus your formula (vertex.z-nearplane.z)/(farplane.z-nearplane.z) doesn't have much sense, all OpenGL knows is gl_Position of 1 vertex in range -w; w, which you've given in the shader, and the screen size which is derived from glViewport values you provided before drawing.
The "projection" is purely mathematical concept, not a specific stage of rendering triangles. Understand projection as a computation, that just stretches the vector in some directions (to map a custom frustum, to a cube -w;w)


Thanks for your answer . One more question , what's the point making clip range equal with perspective parameter ?
